# Excel - Opening second file sets all UDF outputs to #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba, file-io

This is a strange one.

So I have a Workbook, which makes use of a handful of User Defined Functions (written in VBA), that do simple sums. These are working fine.

However, the moment I open a second Workbook, the outputs of all these UDFs change to #VALUE!. If I recalculate the workbook with ctrl + alt + F9, the UDFs output their correct values.

Since recalculating works fine, and the functions aren't throwing any errors, I don't (think) the problem is with the VBA Code... anyone know why this is happening??

Note: It doesn't matter what second file I open, all workbooks have the same effect.

**SOLVED**
The problem was that the UDFs set sheet objects like this:

```
Set Sheet = Worksheets("sample_name")
```

This needed to be changed to:

```
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sample_name")
```

Comment: Check, if you're using `ActiveWorkbook` in your UDF. This would then refer to the newly opened workbook and most likely produce the error. If so, replace it with `ThisWorkbook`...

Comment: Also `ActiveSheet` needs to change to `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`

Comment: There's no use of "Active" in the UDFs. However, they do make use of `Set Sheet = Worksheets("name")`  followed by `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet.Range(...))`
This was the problem! Changed Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name")

Comment: @P4U1 - If you solved the problem, please post it as an "answer". That way it will be easier for others to find.

Comment: I have same problem, but solved. hell good